# Node above other node fails with "cannot parse this coordinate"

Tags: tikz-pgf, programming, draw

I'm Alex stuying automation engineering and have to write my master thesis with tex. Until now, I haven't really used tikz or used a program to draw graphics and exported them to tikz. Now for the control concept (2 degrees of freedom), I wanted to use tikz. I found an example and tried to modify it. Nevertheless, I have problems. One is, when I use this example as defined below, I get the error:

```
! Package tikz Error: Cannot parse this coordinate.

See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.33    \draw
        [-] (y) |- (prectrl2);
?
```

with this code:

```
\tikzstyle{block} = [draw, fill=blue!20, rectangle, 
minimum height=3em, minimum width=3em]
\tikzstyle{sum} = [draw, fill=blue!20, circle, node distance=2cm]
\tikzstyle{input} = [coordinate]
\tikzstyle{output} = [coordinate]
\tikzstyle{pinstyle} = [pin edge={-,thin,black}]

% The block diagram code is probably more verbose than necessary
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2cm]
% We start by placing the blocks
\node [input, name=input] {};
\node [block, right of=input,
        node distance=3cm] (prectrl) {Vorsteuerung};
\node [sum, right of=prectrl,
node distance=3cm] (sum) {};
\node [block, right of=sum] (controller) {Regler};
\node [sum, right of=controller] (sum2) {};
\node [block, right of=sum2] (system) {System};
\node [output, right of=system,
node distance=3.5cm] (output) {};
\node [input, below of=controller] (measurements) {};
\node [input, above of=controller] (prectrl2) {};

% Once the nodes are placed, connecting them is easy. 
\draw [draw,->] (input) -- node {$x_a^*, x_b^*$} (prectrl);
\draw [->] (prectrl) -- node {$x^*$} (sum);
\draw [->] (sum) -- node {$x^*$} (controller);
\draw [->] (controller) -- node {$u_R$} (sum2);
\draw [->] (sum2) -- node {$u$} (system);
\draw [->] (system) -- node [name=y] {$x \rightarrow y= c^T x$}(output);
\draw [-] (y) |- (measurements);
\draw [->] (measurements) -| node[pos=0.99] {$-$}
\draw [-] (y) |- (prectrl2);
\draw [->] (prectrl2) -| node[pos=-6.99] {$-$}
node [near end] {$y_m$} (sum);
\end{tikzpicture}`
```

If I remove either "measurements" or "prectrl2", then everything works fine. My second question is: How do I point the arrow to the second sum?

Hopefully afterwards I can draw an arrow from prectrl to the second sum, which is my goal. I defined prectrl2 and measurements, because I didn't find a possibility to draw the angle directly from "y" to the first sum and from "prectrl" to the second sum.

It would be nice if you can give me a hind, since I'm stuck at this point for over 3 hours.

With kind regards,

Alex

Comment: Hi,  welcome. The problem is the line before, `\draw [->] (measurements) -| node[pos=0.99] {$-$}`, you've forgotten the end coordinate of the path and the `;`.

Comment: Just to let you know that I was reading your statement "Hopefully afterwards I can draw an arrow from prectrl to the second sum, which is my goal. I defined prectrl2 and measurements, because I didn't find a possibility to draw the angle directly from "y" to the first sum and from "prectrl" to the second sum." forward and backward but could not make sense of it. If you post a sketch illustrating what you mean I may be able to do that.

Comment: I posted the picture, how it should look like. I couldn't see the obvious (in germany we say: "I lost sight of the wood for the trees.").

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Torbjørn T. said in his comment, you need to add a node there. And probably you do not really want to use `pos=-6.99`, right? I also replaced `\tikzstyle` by `\tikzset` and load the `positioning` library.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{block/.style={draw, fill=blue!20, rectangle, 
minimum height=3em, minimum width=3em},
sum/.style={draw, fill=blue!20, circle, node distance=2cm},
input/.style ={coordinate},
output/.style ={coordinate},
pinstyle/.style = {pin edge={-,thin,black}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2cm]
% We start by placing the blocks
\node[input] (input) {};
\node[block, right=of input,
        node distance=3cm] (prectrl) {Vorsteuerung};
\node [sum, right=3cm of prectrl] (sum) {};
\node [block, right=of sum] (controller) {Regler};
\node [sum, right=of controller] (sum2) {};
\node [block, right=of sum2] (system) {System};
\node [output, right=3.5cm of system] (output) {};
\node [input, below=of controller] (measurements) {};
\node [input, above=of controller] (prectrl2) {};
% Once the nodes are placed, connecting them is easy. 
\draw [draw,->] (input) -- node {$x_a^*, x_b^*$} (prectrl);
\draw [->] (prectrl) -- node {$x^*$} (sum);
\draw [->] (sum) -- node {$x^*$} (controller);
\draw [->] (controller) -- node {$u_R$} (sum2);
\draw [->] (sum2) -- node {$u$} (system);
\draw [->] (system) -- node [name=y] {$x \rightarrow y= c^T x$}(output);
\draw [-] (y) |- (measurements);
\draw [->] (measurements) -| (sum) node[pos=0.99] {$-$};
\draw [-] (y) |- (prectrl2);
\draw [->] (prectrl2) -| node[pos=0.99] {$-$} node [near end] {$y_m$} (sum);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all,

my problem was, that I didn't recognized, that the part 
`node [near end] {$y_m$} (sum);`
belong to
   `\draw [->] (prectrl2) -| node[pos=-6.99] {$-$}` 
Now, with your help, I understand the example. My code now looks like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}    
\tikzset{block/.style={draw, fill=blue!20, rectangle, 
minimum height=3em, minimum width=3em},
sum/.style={draw, fill=blue!20, circle, node distance=2cm},
input/.style ={coordinate},
output/.style ={coordinate},
pinstyle/.style = {pin edge={-,thin,black}}}

\begin{document}
% The block diagram code is probably more verbose than necessary
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2cm]
% We start by placing the blocks
\node [input, name=input] {};
\node [block, right of=input, node distance=3cm] (prectrl) {Vorsteuerung};
\node [sum, right of=prectrl,node distance=3cm] (sum) {};
\node [block, right of=sum] (controller) {Regler};
\node [sum, right of=controller] (sum2) {};
\node [block, right of=sum2] (system) {System};
\node [output, right of=system,node distance=3.5cm] (output) {};
\node [input, below of=controller] (measurements) {};
\node [input, above of=controller] (prectrl2) {};

% Once the nodes are placed, connecting them is easy. 
\draw [draw,->] (input) -- node {$x_a^*, x_b^*$} (prectrl);
\draw [->] (prectrl) -- node {$x^*$} (sum);
\draw [->] (sum) -- node {$x^*$} (controller);
\draw [->] (controller) -- node {$u_R$} (sum2);
\draw [->] (sum2) -- node {$u$} (system);
\draw [->] (system) -- node [name=y] {$x \rightarrow y= c^T x$}(output);
\draw [-] (y) |- (measurements);
\draw [->] (measurements) -| (sum) node[pos=0.99] {$-$};
\draw [-] (prectrl) |- (prectrl2);
\draw [->] (prectrl2) -| (sum2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Tank you all for your help.

With kind regards,
Alex